# Javascript function to split the text into two strings of the same length

Tags: javascript, string, function, split, word-wrap

Is there a standard javascript function to split a string into two lines of the same (or almost the same lines) without breaking the words.

What I actually want is to:

-leave the text with no changes, if the text contains less than let's say 50 symbols (including spaces),

-otherwise, split it into two lines of the same (almost the same) length.

That is needed to display the text in a good manner, to look nicely.

Examples:

```
Today is Monday.

Today is Monday, tomorrow is Tuesday.  //less than 50 symbols.

Today is Monday, tomorrow is 
Tuesday, after tomorrow is Wednesday.   //splitted into two lines, Tuesday is on the second line.
```

Comment: Does your text end up in a browser? Why not using css in this case?

Comment: No, there's no standard function. You will have to compute it manually.

Comment: Do you want it to be split into two separate variables or do you just want a newline character inserted into the string?

Comment: No, there's no standard JavaScript function. Sometimes one just needs to write a little code. But for future reference, you can refer to [MDN String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to find out which standard methods do exist for String. And of course they have pages for all the standard JavaScript types.

Comment: @Alberto Zaccagni  Thanks for the question. Yes, css breaks the text into two lines, but the second line contains much less than about half of the text.

Comment: ...or you could get clever, and have your JavaScript adjust the width of a wrapping container until the text wraps to 3 lines, then have it back off a bit so it goes back to two.

Comment: Alex Kibler, both ways would be fine. Thank you.

Comment: You can only split strings by its characters, not by its width. Splitting `iiiiWWWW` at position 4 will result in two strings of the same length, but not of the same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple example uses split to find the "middle", though it's not the same "middle" as your example. you can shift the split a few slots to the left using (s.length/2)-6 if you want the first line to usually be shorter push comnes to shove. you might even consider trying (s.length*0.45) to get a little bit to the left; play around and find something that works best for your text.

here's how to find the position of a space near the middle:

```
var s="Today is Monday, tomorrow is Tuesday, after tomorrow is Wednesday."; 
var p=s.slice(s.length/2).split(" ").slice(1).join(" ").length;
s.slice(0, s.length-p) + "\n" + s.slice(s.length-p);

/* == "Today is Monday, tomorrow is Tuesday, 
       after tomorrow is Wednesday."  */
```

edit: keep in mind that "hello".slice( 2.5 ) works in JS.